# The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead

Tags: css, iframe

I've embedded a Google map onto my website in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.map-generator.net/extmap.php?name=Spot&amp;address=los%20angeles%2C%20ca&amp;width=614&amp;height=244&amp;maptype=map&amp;zoom=14&amp;hl=en&amp;t=1298011905" width="614" height="244" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is invalid, and I need to somehow pull off the scrolling aspect in CSS. How would I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```html
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

But it won't work on chrome: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/issues/1142#issuecomment-1959544213

Comment: thanks, 'none' didn't work so i tried 'hidden' and it did. i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @John - Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to only work on Firefox. Am I wrong? Should this work *everywhere*?

Comment: Does this "fix" _still_ not work for Chrome? Any alternative available?

Comment: it does NOT work. its been broken for years now. however in charge of this at W3C must be drunk.

Comment: I don't get how this got accepted and got upvotes. Its clearly NOT the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Late response**

The only solution I found so far is setting overflow to hidden and set width, height to a parent div.

In your case:

```
<div style="width:614px; height:244px;">
    <iframe src="http://www.map-generator.net/extmap.php?name=Spot&amp;address=los%20angeles%2C%20ca&amp;width=614&amp;height=244&amp;maptype=map&amp;zoom=14&amp;hl=en&amp;t=1298011905"width="614" height="244" style="overflow:hidden; width:614px; height:244px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found another solution which worked.

```
<iframe src="...." class="frame-abc" scrolling='no' ></iframe>

.frame-abc {
border:none;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
height:230px;
width:570px; 
}
```

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. First, there's no guarantee the link is trustworthy; and second, when the link inevitably dies, the answer becomes useless. Feel free to summarize or quote some of the content from the link.

Comment: Also, that looks like the same solution. The CSS is declared separately rather than inline, but it still relies on use of `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Seperate class with css is help me to fix the issue in validator.

Comment: And you're still using the scrolling attribute :P