# Issues resolving issues with iframe code using w3.org

Tags: css, html

Im tidying up my code using http://validator.w3.org/

I'm getting these errors:

> Line 143, Column 102: Bad value 280px for attribute height on element
>   iframe: Expected a digit but saw p instead.
>   …crea8tion.com/PP/usercapture/index.php" scrolling="no"
>   height="280px"> Syntax of non-negative integer: One or more digits
>   (0–9). For example: 42 and 0 are valid, but -273 is not

-

> Error Line 143, Column 102: The scrolling attribute on the iframe
>   element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   …crea8tion.com/PP/usercapture/index.php" scrolling="no"
>   height="280px">

---

> Line 282, Column 90: & did not start a character reference. (&
>   probably should have been escaped as &.)
>   …any/332992?trk=vsrp_companies_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A2433719413894427…

From this code

```
<iframe src="http://crea8tion.com/PP/usercapture/index.php" scrolling="no" height="280px"></iframe>
```

I'm uncertain how to resolve these?

Comment: When you copy paste the exact warnings into your favorite search engines, you'll get your answers. ( For example even on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048793/the-scrolling-attribute-on-the-iframe-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead))

Comment: The vote downs seem a little unfair.

Comment: @Dano007 - agree, I uppvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

```
width = non-negative integer
Give the width of the visual content of the element, in CSS pixels.

height = non-negative integer
Give the height of the visual content of the element, in CSS pixels.
```

that means, that the values of width and height always in px and you have to insert just an integer.