# Unable to hide iframe horizontal scroll bars using css

Tags: css, html

http://validator.w3.org/ has returned the following validation error with my code.

> Line 140, Column 109: The scrolling attribute on the iframe element
>   is obsolete. Use CSS instead. …d" scrolling="no"
>   src="http://crea8tion.com/PP/usercapture/index.php">

I've searched google and found the following solution on stackoverflow.

[The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048793/the-scrolling-attribute-on-the-iframe-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead)

So I changed my html to remove scrolling="no" and now my html currently looks like this

```
<iframe class="restricted" src="http://crea8tion.com/PP/usercapture/index.php"></iframe>
```

and my CSS like this

```
.restricted
     {
    width:auto;overflow-y:hidden; height:280px;overflow-x:hidden;

        }
```

But I still have a horizontal scroll bar appearing on my page. What have I missed?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/18649273/961695

Comment: This was a useful part to helping solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iframes are a new document. The inner document could be creating the scrollbar.